# .where query through multiple models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

i want to access every user, which has the same `role` as the `current_user`.
Normally i do stuff like: `User.where(role: current_user.role)` but to keep everything clean i have a nested model called `Account` in which i store basically everything except of the standard devise data like e-mail.

What i want to achieve is something like `User.account.where(role: current_user.account.role)` which is not working unfortunately. Also i read about `.joins` but i dont really get what i can do with that. Anyway i tried to do something like `User.joins(:account).where(role: 1)` without success. Also i tried curly brackets and searched a lot but since i am not a native speaker i dont really know what to search for.

**User.rb**
`has_one :account`

**Account.rb**
`belongs_to :user`

Comment: Please correct above at `User.account` for `has_one` relation

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
User.joins(:account).where('accounts.role': current_user.account.role)
```

Comment: I suppose role is in accounts table. so `where(accounts: {role: current_user.account.role})`

Comment: @mrzasa thanks for the fast response. unfortunately that does not work ( tried it already ). i get this error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.role: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "users"."role" = ? LIMIT ?` but i dont really know what its telling me

Comment: @Ursus your suggestion is not working as well :/ similar error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: accounts.role: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "accounts"."role" = ?`

Comment: Could you post schema,rb fragments with definitions of those tables?

Comment: @GabrielTheCoder the joins stays though. `User.joins(:account).where(accounts: {role: current_user.account.role})`

Comment: @Ursus that worked in console somehow oO thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
Account.where(role: current_user.account.role).includes(:user).map(&:user)
```

Comment: You'll have n+1 query first loading accounts and then user per account in  separate query.